# Disable keyboard avoidance in a bottom sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui, uihostingcontroller, safearea

TLDR: The view modifier `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` does not appear to work when used inside a bottom sheet. Is there a workaround?

In a SwiftUI View, tapping a TextField invokes the keyboard and the Textfield then moves upwards to avoid the keyboard.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var mytext: String = "Some text"   
    var body: some View {      
        VStack {
           Spacer()
           TextField("abc", text: $mytext)
           Spacer()
        }            
    }
}
```

This keyboard avoidance behaviour can be disabled by adding the `.ignoresSafeArea` modifier

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var mytext: String = "Some text"   
    var body: some View {      
        VStack {
           Spacer()
           TextField("abc", text: $mytext)
           Spacer()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)   
    }
}
```

and the TextField no longer moves upwards.

If this technique is applied inside to a view in a bottom sheet it no longer works and the entire sheet is pushed up by the keyboard.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var mytext: String = "Some text"
    @State var isPresented: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.mint
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("abc", text: $mytext)
                    Spacer()
            }
            .presentationDetents( [.fraction(0.33)] )
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried applying `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` to every view thats exposed in the code with no success.

I suspect that the bug is due to the bottom sheet implementation using a UIHostingController internally. This can been seen using Xcode's Debug View Hierarchy tool.

[Others](https://steipete.com/posts/disabling-keyboard-avoidance-in-swiftui-uihostingcontroller/) have described how UIHostingController does not respect the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` modifier and have developed workarounds but these are not applicable here because the UIHostingController is created internally, not explicitly in my code.

Is there any way to get the view inside the sheet to ignore the keyboard and stay put?

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Now, _that_ is how you ask a SO question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Others have described how UIHostingController does not respect the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)` modifier and have developed workarounds but these are not applicable here because the `UIHostingController` is created internally, not explicitly in my code.

The workaround from [Peter Steinberger’s blog post](https://steipete.com/posts/disabling-keyboard-avoidance-in-swiftui-uihostingcontroller/) you’re referring to can actually be used in the context of pure SwiftUI views as well.

You’d need to find the enclosing hosting view first, which can be achieved either by installing a `UIViewRepresentable` and traversing the underlying view hierarchy or by using a library that helps with this task. Once found, you’d swizzle its `keyboardWillShowWithNotification:` and `keyboardWillHideWithNotification:` methods to turn them into noops.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/lukaskubanek/57d0faea1de51728ceb3196667d7810f) is a gist of how this could look like. The snippet uses [SwiftUI Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) for finding the hosting view (here applied only on iOS 17), [InterposeKit](https://github.com/steipete/InterposeKit) for swizzling, and finally, a custom associated objects API for storing off a flag indicating whether the patch has already been applied to a particular hosting view.

To make use of the `keyboardAvoidanceDisabled()` modifier, you’d simply attach it to the view that gets affected by keyboard avoidance.

Please keep in mind that this patch uses private API!

Comment: Thanks Lukáš, that appears to fill the missing pieces of the puzzle. Are you using a wrapper around objc_setAssociatedObject and objc_setAssociatedObject?

Comment: Exactly! I have a custom wrapper in place, very similar to [this implementation](https://github.com/lukaskollmer/RuntimeKit/blob/master/RuntimeKit/Sources/AssociatedObject.swift).

Comment: Marking as correct because @LukášKubánek's answer solves the technical question of how to override methods of a UIHostingView thats been created by the framework, no explicitly created by our code. To get this to work on a bottom sheet or popover I needed to scope the inrtrospection to look at ancestor views, ie  `self.introspect(.viewController, on:  .iOS(.v17) , scope: .ancestor ) { viewController in`. The introspection and method overriding appear work, but the keyboard still pushes the entire UI up the screen.

Comment: To be frank, I feel the Apple sheet implementation is perhaps too opinionated to be useful in many situations. Better to use a third party solution like  [DynamicOverlay](https://github.com/faberNovel/DynamicOverlay) instead.

Comment: @DaveRobertson Thanks for accepting my answer!

Re introspecting the ancestor: I guess this should be equal to reaching to the parent view controller as per the code I shared.

Re pushing UI up the screen: What do you mean by the entire UI? Do you mean the UI within the sheet or in the background? If the latter, you might consider applying the modifier to the background view as well.